# Can I arbitrarily close tags in Jade?

Tags: pug, mean-stack

I've been trying in vain to produce the following HTML in Jade:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a> - lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure it's possible, but the closest thing I could find was self-closing tags. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I experimented with @TheOsirian's technique, and found that I can also do stuff like this:

```
ul
 li
  a(href="http://google.com") Item
  em|  - lorem ipsum 
  strong| this is bold
```

Which will generate this HTML:

```
    <ul>
       <li>
           <a href="http://google.com">Item</a><em> - lorem ipsum </em><strong>this is bold</strong>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Pretty cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the desired output:

```
ul
 li
  a(href="http://google.com") Item
  |  - lorem ipsum
```

Both `<a>` and the text are inside `<li>` but the text isn't inside `<a>` so it won't be part of `<a>` but will still be part of `<li>`.